# How can i connect JavaScript to a SQL server?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I work as an intern in a manufacturing company that designed a HTML web page run by JavaScript that is supposed to show real time statistics of the machine lines.

To do this it must connect to a SQL server in real time to obtain the data that it needs to display charts and reports.

I have good knowledge of other programming languages but I'm a rookie at JavaScript and I would like to know the safest way to do this, since the database contains sensitive data.

Can this be done?

Comment: Connect it directly? Learn NodeJS. Connect it via a website? Learn web services with a middle-tier (server side) language like PHP, Dot Net, Python -- or NodeJS). This is too broad of a topic for Stack Overflow, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of middleman to connect to the database. Since you want to do this with JavaScript, I suggest you checkout [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) . You can then build a simple API that when consumed it will return the data required. One benefit of building an API is you will be able to consume it from the website that is already built without having to make any changes in the back end. You can simply use fetch the data from the front end using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this directly with Javascript in your HTML file in client-side(It is not secure).
Do this with any language that you know on the server side and read those data using ajax and display them in your HTML file.